# Mock a method and getting in return a parameter of the passed class

Tags: java, mockito

I have a class, THAT.class, as follows:

```
class THAT {
    int aVar;
}
```

Actually I want to mock a method, METH, of a class, THIS, taking the class THAT as a parameter. And as return I want to have the variable aVar of the THAT class as follows:

```
Mockito.when(THIS.METH (Matchers.any(THAT.class), ).thenReturn(THAT.aVar);
```

How may I realize that?

Comment: Please read about java naming conventions. Your usage of CASING confuses people that are used to never ever have class names in all uppercase. Seriously: follow standard conventions instead of inventing your own ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ArgumentCaptor` to capture the argument and return the value from it.

```
final ArgumentCaptor<THAT> thatCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(THAT.class);

doAnswer (invocation -> {
   return thatCaptor.getValue().getAVar()//use the variable directly if its public
}).when(This).METH(thatCaptor.capture());
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct about the "technical way" of solving your problem.

But you should understand: probably you are using "mocking" the wrong way.

You see, you only use mocks in order to achieve "just enough" control over your "code under test" as needed.  Meaning: as soon as you start doing "complicated" things within your mocking specifications, chances are that you created *hard to test* production code - and that you now turn to the band-aid of using *complex* test case setup to fix that.

Whereas you should be doing something else: looking into ways to rework your production code. So that it becomes *easy to test* instead.

Like in: instead of "allowing" for any kind of `That` object - only expect and use a **specific** instance. As in:

```
when(foo.bar(whatever)).thenReturn(whatever);
```

There is no point in allowing for *arbitrary* input. You should rather strive to *minimize* the degrees of "freedom" that your mocks are specified for.

Comment: Yes, very helpful .. I think there is some work to do to ameliorate the architecture of my classes and the dependencies ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use doAnswer to return call-specific values

```
doAnswer (invocation -> {
   return invocation.getArgument(0);
}).when(This.METH(Matchers.any(THAT.class)));
```